# Esconder um diretório do site no Dev tools

Tags: javascript

eu fiz um site a pouco tempo e percebi que é possível ver alguns diretórios do site no Developer Tools do Google Chrome (Não testei essa ferramenta em outros navegadores). E fiquei meio preocupado com isso pois uma dica de segurança é sempre tentar colocar nomes diferentes no diretório que gerencia o conteúdo do site, porém com esse recurso do Dev Tools fica meio inútil essa dica de segurança. Percebi que outros sites mais avançados não mostra o diretório de gerenciamento de conteúdo.

Existe algum script ou forma que eu possa ocultar o diretório do meu sistema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele não exibe o diretório completo, se um diretório tem os arquivos A, B e C e a página carrega apenas A e C, ele listará A e C dentro desse diretório. Até onde sei o que se faz muito é servir seu site através de CDN que reflete os seus arquivos e alguns tem algumas funcionalidades de segurança pra proteger o servidor

Comment: @RômuloGabrielRodrigues Você tem algum link onde eu posso saber mais sobre esse CDN que você mencionou?

Comment: Isso aqui não é dica, é gambiarra: "uma dica de segurança é sempre tentar colocar nomes diferentes no diretório que gerencia o conteúdo do site" - Ou você protege o diretório, ou põe fora da raiz do site se não é coisa para ser acessada diretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque você está servindo recursos para o site que estão localizados dentro do seu diretório administrativo `sistema/class/uploads`.

Até pode ser correto que o upload seja feito dentro desse diretório que somente ele tenha permissão de escrita.

Mas para consumir esses recursos você pode utilizar uma solução de "CDN", como sugerido nos comentários. As soulções mais simples seriam: criar um subdomínio apontando para esse caminho ou mapear um diretório virtual para fora do diretório `sistema`

Outro detalhe é que a recomendação não é apenas ocultar o diretório administrativo do site, ele de fato nem deveria existir.

Deveria ser uma aplicação diferente e isolada sem compartilhar diretamente o mesmo ambiente do client. Que por sua vez não deve acessar diretamente o banco de dados e compartilhar o mínimo possível dos objetos de negócio.

Comment: Você tem algum link onde eu posso saber mais sobre esse CDN que você mencionou?

Comment: https://blog.webtuga.pt/o-que-e-um-cdn-content-delivery-network/, mas não se apegue a isso, foi apenas uma citação de exemplo.

Comment: Certo, obrigado!